# Let $f:[a,b]] \to \mathbb{R}$ absolutely continuous and increasing function. Prove $\int_A f'd\lambda=\lambda(f(A))$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be absolutely continuous and increasing function.
> Prove $$\int_A f'd\lambda=\lambda(f(A))$$
> for all $A \subset [a,b]$ measurable.

**My idea is,**

$f$ absolutely continuous and increasing function. Then $f$ is integrable.

Define
$$\mu:\mathbb{I} \rightarrow [0,\infty], \qquad \mu([a,b])=\int f'(x)dx.$$

Consider
$$\mu([a,b])=f(b)-f(a)=\lambda([f(a),f(b)])=\lambda(f([a,b])).$$
Now, $\mu=\lambda \circ f\;$ in $\;\mathbb{I}\;$ and $\;\mu([a,b])<\infty.$

Then, by Caratheodory's Theorem, $\overline{\mu}$ is a unique extension.

$$\implies \overline{\mu}=\mu=\lambda \circ f \text{ in } \mathbb{B}.$$

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your thought and effort on this problem?

Comment: Prove the result for intervals $A$. Then use the fact that all measurable sets can be approximated by unions of intervals.

Comment: It is not obvious that $\lambda(f(A))$ is a measure, so approximation works only when you prove that this is a measure.

Comment: It's clearly true for intervals, so if $A$ is a measurable set, use the definition of the Lebesgue measure to find a finite sequence of disjoint intervals $I_j$ that cover $A$ and are such that $\lambda (A)>\sum \lambda (I_j)-\epsilon.$

Comment: My idea is, 

$f$ absolutely continuous and increasing function. Then $f$ is integrable.

Define, 
$$  \mu:\mathbb{I} \rightarrow [0,\infty] $$
$$  \mu([a,b])=\int f'(x)dx $$

Consider,
 $$\mu([a,b])=f(b)-f(a)=\lambda([f(a),f(b)])=\lambda(f([a,b]))$$
Now ,  $\mu=\lambda \circ f$ en $\mathbb{I}$ and $\mu([a,b])<\infty$

Then, by Caratheodory's Theorem $\overline{\mu}$ is a unique extension.

$\Rightarrow$$\overline{\mu}=\mu=\lambda \circ f$ in $\mathbb{B}$

Answer (score 1):

Going from intervals to measurable sets is not easy. So I am trying the following:
Let $g(x)=x+f(x)$. Since $g$ is absolutely continuous and strictly increasing, hence one-to-one, it is easy to see that the result holds with $g$ in place of $f$. It remains only to show that $\lambda(g(A))=\lambda(f(A))+\lambda(A)$. I think I am struck here!

Answer (score 0):

I know I am very late to the party but you can solve the problem in the following way:

Show it for intervals, then for open sets(Every open set is a countable disjoint union of open intervals), then for $G_\delta$ sets (here use that $g$ is injective), then show it works for measure $0$ sets (standard fact), then finally show it for measurable set (As these are $G_\delta$ minus set of measure $0$.